# ArgumentParser is not working well if we start with assigned app on the commandline

Tags: python, argparse

I use argparse many years and start the scripts with the default app linked to .py.

Recently it likes that argparse do nothing.  If I starts with
py test.py -d
or
python script.py -d
is everthing normal.

In past, there was no problem.  I change my startup scripts with prolog: "python".

```
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', help='debug mode', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(sys.version)
    print(args)
    print(args.debug)
```

What we has a result:

```
c:\Work>test.py -d
3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Namespace(debug=False)
False

c:\Work>python test.py -d
3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Namespace(debug=True)
True
```

Comment: I'd also look at `sys.argv`, and try the `-h` help.  I'm not aware of any changes in Python versions that should produce this difference.  So my best guess is that it's referencing differenent `test.py` scripts.

Comment: I add print(sys.argv) in the code example and found that the parameters are not available.  So this is a Windows problem (Windows 10 and Windows 7).

Comment: I haven't used Windows in some time, but recall that setting up the 'shebang' (#!python) business is trickier than on linux.

Answer (score 0):

The association in Windows 10 - Settings (Choose default apps by file type) was setting to "Python".
I change is no to "Python launch" and everthing is now working well.